# How can i sum some numbers with same value in A column?

Tags: vba, excel, sum

i have in A column some names and in b column some numbers like:

```
jimmy 4
jimmy 4
carl  8
john  8
```

I need to sum jimmy's numbers. I mean, if there are some same values in A colum the sum the B numbers of that name. So jimmy = 8.
How can i do it? I'm very new in vba so the easy things for me are not so easy :)

EDIT, the macro:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim path As String
    Dim openWb As Workbook
    Dim openWs As Worksheet
    Dim DataInizio As String
    Dim DataFine As String

    path = "C:\Me\Desktop\example.xls"

    Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook

    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("details")

    Set Logore = thiswb.Sheets("Log")

    With openWs
         start = CDate(InputBox("start (gg/mm/aaaa)"))
         end = CDate(InputBox("end (gg/mm/aaaa)"))
         Sheets("details").Select

         LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         dRow = 2

         For r = 2 To LR
         If Cells(r, 1) >= start And Cells(r, 1) <= end Then
         ' Do un nome alle colonne nel file di log indicandone la posizione
           ore = Range("K" & r)
           nome = Range("J" & r)
           totore = totore + ore
              If ore <> 8 Then
                Range("A" & r & ",J" & r & ",D" & r & ",K" & r).Copy Logore.Cells(dRow, 1)
                rigatot = dRow
                dRow = dRow + 1
              End If
              If nome <> Range("J" & r + 1) Then
                  If totore <> 40 Then
                    Logore.Cells(dRow, 5) = totore
                  End If
                  totore = 0
              End If
          End If
         Next
         thiswb.Sheets("Log").Activate
    End With
    openWb.Close (False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need VBA for this? You can use Excel formula for this? `SumIf` or `Sumproduct`?

Comment: because i have already a macro and this would be an implemantion

Comment: Why not use `SumIf` or `Sumproduct` in VBA then using `Application.WorkSheetFunction` I would recommend recording a macro and then amending the code... Give it a try and if you are stuck then post the code that you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: I'm going to write the code. Thanks. Just a second :)

Comment: To get you started... here are two formulas which you can convert to VBA `=SUMIF(A1:A4,"Jimmy",B1:B4)`, `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A4="Jimmy")*(B1:B4))`

Comment: It doesn't show me that you incorporated the suggestion that i gave above?

Comment: your suggestion isn't implemented sorry because in meanwhile you seggest me that part i was going to edit my answere

Comment: As an additional suggestion, you could do this in seconds by using a pivot table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this macro will sum up the values and reprint them as a new list. You can specify the columns as String parameters in your Main sub.

---

`CollectArray "A", "D"` - collects array from column `A` and removes duplicates from it and then prints it to column `D`

`DoSum "D", "E", "A", "B"` - summs up all values for column `D` and writes them to column `E` - gets the match from column `A` & values from column `B`

---

before:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    CollectArray "A", "D"

    DoSum "D", "E", "A", "B"

End Sub


' collect array from a specific column and print it to a new one without duplicates
' params:
'           fromColumn - this is the column you need to remove duplicates from
'           toColumn - this will reprint the array without the duplicates
Sub CollectArray(fromColumn As String, toColumn As String)

    ReDim arr(0) As String

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Range(fromColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        arr(UBound(arr)) = Range(fromColumn & i)
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
    RemoveDuplicate arr
    Range(toColumn & "1:" & toColumn & Range(toColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Range(toColumn & i + 1) = arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub


' sums up values from one column against the other column
' params:
'           fromColumn - this is the column with string to match against
'           toColumn - this is where the SUM will be printed to
'           originalColumn - this is the original column including duplicate
'           valueColumn - this is the column with the values to sum
Private Sub DoSum(fromColumn As String, toColumn As String, originalColumn As String, valueColumn As String)
    Range(toColumn & "1:" & toColumn & Range(toColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Range(fromColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(toColumn & i) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(originalColumn & ":" & originalColumn), Range(fromColumn & i), Range(valueColumn & ":" & valueColumn))
    Next i
End Sub


Private Sub RemoveDuplicate(ByRef StringArray() As String)
    Dim lowBound$, UpBound&, A&, B&, cur&, tempArray() As String
    If (Not StringArray) = True Then Exit Sub
    lowBound = LBound(StringArray): UpBound = UBound(StringArray)
    ReDim tempArray(lowBound To UpBound)
    cur = lowBound: tempArray(cur) = StringArray(lowBound)
    For A = lowBound + 1 To UpBound
        For B = lowBound To cur
            If LenB(tempArray(B)) = LenB(StringArray(A)) Then
                If InStrB(1, StringArray(A), tempArray(B), vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then Exit For
            End If
        Next B
        If B > cur Then cur = B
        tempArray(cur) = StringArray(A)
    Next A
    ReDim Preserve tempArray(lowBound To cur): StringArray = tempArray
End Sub
```

after:

[image]

Comment: Oh god it's so big o.O can you help me to implement the part i need in my code? Really i'm a beginner and this macro scared me ahah

Comment: I feel that my answer answers your original question. If it's helpful then you can accept it. If you have another question then ask a new one because joining the two macros with a good explanation from you on when and how to do it sounds to me like a good new question. Try doing it yourself and if you can't then come back and ask a new question.

Comment: In the macro I have provided you only need to worry about the `Main()`. It's your navigational configurator. That is you need to send the correct parameters (column names) to have the macro do all the work for you.