# Summing up rows in Excel if rows contain identical string

Tags: excel, function

I have a table with two columns. One column has names, the second column has numbers:

```
|-------|------|
| Names | Nums |
|-------|------|
| Name1 |  2   |
| Name5 |  3   |
| Name7 |  1   |
| Name1 |  1   |
| Some4 |  5   |
| Yay55 |  2   |
| Name1 |  1   |
| Name5 |  1   |
| Name5 |  7   |
| Name1 |  8   |
| Yay55 |  3   |
| Yay55 |  1   |
| Name1 |  0   |
|-------|------|
```

I am looking to consolidate this table to have unique `Names` only and a sum of all occurrences in the `Nums` column. Is it possible to achieve it without VB, and using only Excel functions?

Just to add a note, it should not be considered a duplicate question. I am aware of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490996/how-can-i-sum-some-numbers-with-same-value-in-a-column), that is similar, but asks about VB.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/460780-array-formula-remove-duplicates-list.html), [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) and [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/460154-formula-extract-unique-values-array-2.html). Also you can use a pivot table to summarize your data by name and using the sum of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Pivot Table` to summarize your data `by name` and using the `sum of values`.

**I.e.:**

**Creating the table:**

[image]

**Organizing data:**

[image]

Comment: Pivot tables are the way to go.  Another option would be to use a sumifs